# can use Google cloud CDN to cache video

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

Can use google cloud cdn to cache video to help video load faster ???

I'm building a website for livestream in Asia, I wonder if can use google cloud cdn for that ??

Answer (score 0):

The GCP website has a [section on live streaming](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/use-cases/live-streaming/) including a [reference architecture](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/architecture/live-streaming/) show an example way to implement it.

You might also like [Anvato](https://www.anvato.com/products/live-streaming/), a recent addition to GCP, which provides a complete end-to-end live streaming solution.